# Fetch record from database using stored procedure with month and year condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to fetch record from database by getting and parsing year and month from date parameter. Here is the code in `Where` clause in my stored procedure:

```
(MONTH(ai.InstallmentDueDate)) = (MONTH(@DueDate)) 
AND (YEAR(ai.InstallmentDueDate)) = (YEAR(ai.InstallmentDueDate))
```

The month clause works perfectly, but it returns all the years data of that month. Please tell me what to do. So that it returns data of that specific year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you required?

```
(MONTH(ai.InstallmentDueDate)) = (MONTH(@DueDate)) 
AND (YEAR(ai.InstallmentDueDate)) = (YEAR(@DueDate))
```

But I think simply passing the parameter without applying any function can achieve what you want.

```
ai.InstallmentDueDate = @DueDate
```

(Be careful when you use functions in where clause. It's a performance hit)

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the parameter in the year, that's why it's not working.

Check your original post, you're comparing the ai.InstallmentDueDate to itself. You need to compare it against the year of the passed parameter

```
(MONTH(ai.InstallmentDueDate)) = (MONTH(@DueDate)) 
AND (YEAR(ai.InstallmentDueDate)) = (YEAR(@DueDate))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE ai.InstallmentDueDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @DueDate), 0)
AND   ai.InstallmentDueDate <  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @DueDate) + 1, 0)
```